# Mongoose populate not working for nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

#### Client.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const clientSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true, default: "" },
    }, {
        timestamps: true
    }
);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Client", clientSchema);
```

#### User.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: { type: String, required: true, default: "" },
        clients: [{
                client: {
                    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: "Client",
                    default: null
                },
                user_group: {
                    type: Number
                    default: null
                }
            }]
    }, { timestamps: true });
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

#### auth.js (Where trying to populate Clients)

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const Client = require("../models/Client");
router.post("/users", (req, res) => {
    let params = req.body;
    let total_client = [];
    User.findOne({
        email: params.email
    })
    .populate({
         path: "clients.client",
         model: Client
      })
      .exec((err, user) => {
          console.log(user);
          res.send(user);
       });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Please check the above code. I have given code examples of my two models user.js and client.js. In user schema, I have referenced client inside an array object. While querying user, the client is not population. Please help me to get this thing done. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved this problem just adding an extra parameter in module export of client.js file**

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("Client", clientSchema, "client");
```

Answer (score 0):

The following expects you to provide a name in the json body of your post request (your example uses email which does not exist in the user model).  Also, your model is already defining the ref: Client and so you can simplify your request to just include the path `clients.client`.

```
router.post("/users", async (req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ name: name }).populate('clients.client').exec();
    res.send(user);
});
```